# Can rails get the next id after destroying a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose that I have two records in database:

Dogs table:
id:1, name:Paotzu 
id:3, name:Baozi

now I am going to destroy the id 3 (`Dog.find(3).destroy`)
and then the table is being that:

Dogs table:
id:1, name:Paotzu 

OK, now I have a question, 
If I don't create a new record, how can I get the `Next ID` in `rails console` ? 
Somebody told me `Dog.last.id + 1`, but it is incorrect. 
Because if I type `Dog.last.id + 1`, I will get `2`, but I want get `4` (that's I've created.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@dog_rec = Dog.find(3).destroy 
@next_rec = Dog.find(:first, :conditions => ["id > ?", @dog_rec.id])
```

rails can do anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy new record will get id automatically, why you are required such thinks to do.

Comment: I know that, I am just curious.
If I haven't created a record, how can get that?

Answer (score 0):

This would do it

```
Dog.where("created_at > ?", 30.days.ago).order("created_at DESC").first.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom SQL query (this one is for MySQL):

```
sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Dogs'"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
result.each(as: :hash).first['Auto_increment']
#=> 4
```